# 301 redirect cause redirection loop in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redirect

I want to redirect my heroku  domain "mighty-reef-1550.herokuapp.com" to my subdomain "www.foo.com" to avoid SEO duplication penalty.

For that i tried to make a 301 redirection from my routes.rb file

Here is what i did :

```
    constraints(:host => /https://mighty-reef-1550.herokuapp.com/) do
      match "/(*path)" => redirect {|params, req| "https://www.foo.com/#{params[:path]}"},  via: [:get, :post]
    end
```

This doesn't work and give me a redirection loop.
What i did wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're including the protocol in your host. Try:

```
constraints(:host => /mighty-reef-1550.herokuapp.com/) do
```

Also you might want to redirect to

```
//www.foo.com/#{params[:path]}
```

If you're interested in preserving the protocol (HTTPS -> HTTPS, HTTP -> HTTP)

Comment: when i do this //www.foo.com/#{params[:path]} i have a non crypted google error

Comment: What does it say exactly? and where? Is it in the corner of the browser related to SSL certificates ?